How to create a custom method for getting the inner text of an element using Puppeteer with TypeScript
I have the below code where I want to get the inner text from the HTML element.
import puppeteer, { Page } from 'puppeteer';

const main = async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url);

  const book_title = await page.$eval(
      'h1.Text__title1',
      (el: HTMLHeadingElement) => el.innerText
  );
}

As for getting the innerText for other elements, I have to write the same code everytime, so I am creating a reusable method called getInnerText.
async function getInnerText<T extends HTMLElement>(
    page: Page,
    selector: string
): Promise<string | null> {
    const innerText = await page.$eval(
        selector,
        (el: T) => el.innerText
    ) as string | null;
    return innerText;
}

And then I can call the function as below:
const book_title = await getInnerText<HTMLHeadingElement>(page, 'h1.Text__title1')

But in the custom method definition, I am getting the below compiler error in VS code at (el: T) => el.innerText:

Argument of type '(el: T) => string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | EvaluateFuncWith<Element, []>'.
Type '(el: T) => string' is not assignable to type 'EvaluateFuncWith<Element, []>'.
Types of parameters 'el' and 'params_0' are incompatible.
Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'T'.
'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'Element'.

How can I fix this compiler error?

What's the advantage of the generics here: getInnerText<HTMLHeadingElement>(page, 'h1.Text__title1')? Why not just getInnerText(page, 'h1.Text__title1') and let it work with any HTML element? I don't think type safety will really solve any errors here or increase clarity, since the function returns a string regardless of the element type and all HTML elements have innerText (I'd use textContent, but that's another story...). It's a lot of added verbosity burden on the caller without benefit.

@ggorlen Thanks for the comment. Using textContent fixes the error. Also if I want to use innerText instead, the accepted answer here works as well.
